# Dynamically create select options on the fly

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have 2 selects, one with data and other one empty. When first one is selected, I catch it using a switch. Now, depending on the value, I want to create option elements and put them inside empty select.

Let's say I have an array of values

```
var values = ['Hello', 'world', 'etc']
```

When selected

```
selected(event) {
  var name;
  switch (event.target.value) {
    case 'roth':
       // append values as options into select, using foreach
       // such as:
       // <option value="hello">Hello</option>
    ...
  }
}
```

---

This is select in my template:

```
<select class="form-control" :id="selection">
    <option selected="" disabled="" value="0"></option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just define an empty array for options for second `select`, and push values with your switch/case. Later you can use that values with `v-for`
For example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    selectValues: ['Hello', 'world', 'etc'],
    secondarySelectValues: [],
  },
  methods: {
    handleChange: function(e) {
      switch (e.target.value) {
        case 'Hello':
          this.secondarySelectValues = [];
          this.secondarySelectValues.push('this', 'is', 'hello');
          break;
        case 'world':
          this.secondarySelectValues = [];
          this.secondarySelectValues.push('this', 'is', 'world')
          break;
        case 'etc':
          this.secondarySelectValues = [];
          this.secondarySelectValues.push('this', 'is', 'etc')
          break;
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2"></script>
<div id="app">

  <select class="form-control" @change="handleChange">
    <option v-for="selectValue in selectValues" :value="selectValue">{{ selectValue }}</option>
  </select>

  <select class="form-control secondary">
    <option v-for="secondarySelectValue in secondarySelectValues" :value="secondarySelectValue">{{ secondarySelectValue }}</option>
  </select>

</div>
```